# How to make a button lose focus when page is loaded

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

When my JSP page gets loaded, the button (actually an image button with `onfocus` property) gets focused. So, on pressing enter it gets clicked. It is a small, part of a bigger problem. How can I make the button lose focus when page is loaded?

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div onkeypress =handleEnter()>
name <input  type="text" src='Create.gif' >
</br>
<input  type="image" src='Create.gif' onclick="alert('not done')">
<input  type="image" src='Create.gif' onclick="alert('done')">
</div>
</body>
<script>
function handleEnter()
{
if(window.event.keyCode==13)
{
alert('nothing');
event.cancelBubble=true;
}
}
</script>
</html>
```

Both the alert box for nothing and not done has been shown.

Comment: post your code here ..

Comment: Set focus on some other control, like a text box, etc.

Comment: @theghostofc how to do that?

Comment: use $("#textfield").focus(); to deviate the focus to someother element as @theghostofc told.

Comment: Can you tell javascript for that

Comment: is there any tabindex property set for that button?

Comment: You don't need JavaScript at all. See my answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19155399/1317805

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `autofocus` HTML attribute ([specification reference](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#autofocusing-a-form-control%3a-the-autofocus-attribute)) to automatically focus a different element on page load. I'm not sure how this would get applied with JSP, however in pure HTML this would be something along the lines of:

```html
<button>My Button</button>
<button autofocus>My Other Button</button>
```

Here's a [JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/JamesD/q2trj/).

Answer (score 0):

I would modify this line :

```
<input  type="text" src='Create.gif' >
```

to

```
<input  type="text" id="textbox" src='Create.gif' >
<script>
//$('#textbox').focus() //If your using jQuery
document.getElementById('textbox').focus()
</script>
```

This would shift the focus to the text box rather than the image button

Give your textbox an **id** and use that **id** to set the focus to that element.

```
document.getElementById('textbox').focus()
```

Comment: Can you tell me javascritpt for this